# how can i detect the last typed word from a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I want to detect the last typed word from a textbox.
For example if i type Test in the textbox for each keypress it should return the currently typed character.

Here is what i am trying

```
  $(".text").live("keyup",function(e)
  {
    var content=$('.text').val();
    var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf("");
    var laststing = content.substring(0,lastIndex);
    alert(laststing);

});
```

Comment: You question is ambiguous. *"I want to detect the last typed word.."* and *"..should return the currently typed character."*. You need word or character?

Comment: Word or character? You have word in title and character in body.

Comment: If it is word then: `$(this).val().split(' ').pop();`

Comment: @Dhruvin Sukhadiya When editing, please try to fix everything in a post. Also, please read the description of a tag before adding it. You tried to add the API tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5098766), but that tag says "do not use this tag" in it's description. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".text").on("blur", function (e) {
    var content = $('.text').val();
    var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf(" ");
    var laststing = content.substring(lastIndex);
    alert(laststing);

});
```

I think blur event is a better option

http://jsfiddle.net/3gkzC/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$(".text").live("keyup", function (e) {
    var content = $('.text').val();
    var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf(" "); //Find last index of space
    var laststing = content.substring(lastIndex); //Find rest of charcters
    alert(laststing);
});
```

*OR*, You can use `.split()`

```
$(".text").live("keyup", function (e) {
    alert($(this).val().split(' ').pop()); //Simplest                                        
});
```

Comment: I would just replace live() with on().

Comment: @nevermind, I would need to know jQuery version for that. If OP is using version earlier than 1.7 it will throw error

Comment: +1 for the "OR". As an added option (because Op is unclear), `split('')` will help in returning last character instead of word.

Comment: @abhitalks, Yep problem is that OP has not clarified quires

Answer (score 1):

use .on instead .live

.live //jquery 1.3+

.on //jquery 1.7+

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function ()  {

 $(".text").on("keyup",function(e)
  {
    var content=$('.text').val();
    var lastIndex = content.lastIndexOf("");
    var laststing = content.substring(0,lastIndex);
    alert(laststing);

}); 
});

    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4UsX/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like this :

```
$(".text").on("keyup",function(e) {
    var arrayString = $('.text').val().split(""); // Create an array with all characters
    var lastString = arrayString.pop(); // Get the last character
    alert(lastString);
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6kqTf/2/)

This code provides the last **character** and not last word.

---

*Reference*

- [MDN split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [MDN pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)